# How to suppress jshint W030 warning on "use strict" statement in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jshint, suppress-warnings

I use jshint extension in VSCode. Even for the simplest JS file like this

```
{
    "use strict";

    let a = "Hello world!";
    console.log(a);
}
```

I get the warning:

```
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression. jshint(W030) [Ln 2, Col 5]
```

How to suppress this warning?

Comment: Maybe use this flag in your `.jshint` file (or whatever they call it): https://jshint.com/docs/options/#expr I don't know why you are getting that though.

Comment: @Mark, it doesn't work for me, because the warning we discuss might be quite useful sometimes. So I do not want to suppress it generally, I just want this warning will not be shown specifically for "use strict" statement, which is absolutely correct and acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding at the end of the line with that problem this comment  //jshint ignore:line

For instance:

```
{   
"use strict"; //jshint ignore:line 
let a = "Hello world!";
console.log(a); 
}
```

Comment: Maybe, maybe. But your proposal also make the source code "defect", just like discussed warning does.